# PHP array_diff output - Not clear

Tags: php, arrays

Here are the arrays.

```
Array1
(
[439] => dsaffsdfdfdfsffdsf
[379] => 3454
[375] => 3 ///why is it removed in the resulting array?
[436] => Fdsafdfsdf
[432] => 3  /// this one too
[431] => 2
[385] => 499
[434] => 3501
[435] => 2013-01-16
[430] => 1
[440] => fsdzsdaffdsfffdsf
[406] => YES
[438] => 32442344324324234
[376] => 3
)

Array2
(
[376] => 3
[385] => 499
)

array_diff(array1, array2)

result
(
[439] => dsaffsdfdfdfsffdsf
[379] => 3454
[436] => Fdsafdfsdf
[431] => 2
[434] => 3501
[435] => 2013-01-16
[430] => 1
[440] => fsdzsdaffdsfffdsf
[406] => YES
[438] => 32442344324324234
)
```

Looks weird to me. Any idea? Its removing based on value?

I just want `Array2` elements removed from `Array1`

Comment: RTFM :) `array_diff` - Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: It's removing based on value, **and the documentation says so**. There's even an example that shows exactly this behavior. Perhaps you are looking for [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

Comment: Hmmm.. I didn't think so. I will try the assoc one. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinRave: Please don't *try* the assoc version. Just read the docs and *decide* if it does what you want. Programming is not randomly typing stuff until something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manual is your best friend:**

- [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference.
- [array_diff_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference. Unlike array_diff() the array keys are also used in the comparison.
- [array_diff_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) Compares the keys from array1 against the keys from array2 and returns the difference. This function is like array_diff() except the comparison is done on the keys instead of the values.